# Merging 2 dataframes in python

Tags: python, r, pandas, left-join, data-science

I am translating the R code into python. They are merging 2 dataset:

```
Df1 with columnName {Product, trade, volume,date,address,adm2}
Df2 with columnName {Product, trade, volume, searchText}
```

In R they have used the following code:

```
Df2<-read_csv(here("ProductSales2019.csv")) %>% mutate(year=2019) %>% 

left_join(Df1,by=c('Product','address',"volume")) %>% mutate(date=as.character(date))
```

I tried the same thing in python with the following code:

```
Df2 = pd.merge(Df2, Df1, how="left", left_on=["Product","searchText","volume"],right_on=["Product","address","volume"])
```

Note that `(address in Df1 = searchText in df2)`, have same values but different columnames and also I added the `year` column to `Df2`.I get the merged result without any error but I am getting the `date` column of Merged `Df2` as `nan`. and also the size of dataset I got in R is different then in python. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: If you want to match columns with different names in R, don't you need to specify them as you are doing in Python? LIke `by = c("searchText" = "address", ...)`

Comment: Did you add column "date" in python? Df2.loc[:,'date'] = 2019.

Comment: Yes, I added column "date"